# How do I show a progress bar whilst my sub routine is running?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to work out how to get my progress bar to show the progress of the subroutine below. Does anyone have any ideas how to get the ball rolling on this one?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

[image: This is my progress bar]

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

'*****************************

'Direct Data
Sheet4.Activate
Call Test1
Call Test2
Call Test3
Call Test4
'Return to Welcome Page
Sheet8.Activate
'*****************************

'Determine how many seconds the code took to run
 MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", 
vbInformation


End Sub
```

Comment: [Like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87818/23788). Anything else requires you to implement the logic in the form's code-behind, which makes the progress indicator un-reusable.

Comment: Also: your code will likely complete even slower with progress indication (be it on a form or in the app status bar). `Sheet4.Activate` is hinting at a ton of implicit `ActiveSheet` references in these procedures - consider making the code as efficient as possible ([codereview.se] can help you with that), and then, if it's still running for too long, *then* make a progress indicator for it.

Comment: It is not clear where the long running code resides. If it resides in User Form, maybe you can simply add a colored label to this form and increase the length of it when the code did some progress. Another more complicated way is to create second User Form which will contain the Progress Label and this second User Form will have Event which will call back to first User Form where the long running operation runs after this Progress Form was activated (more info [here](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Microsoft-Visual-Basic-6-0/dp/B00006L568)).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use for a progress bar:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Processing... " & CInt(nRow / nLastRow * 100) & "% " & String(CInt(nRow / nLastRow * 100), ChrW(9609)) 
DoEvents ' optional
```

`nRow` is the increment number

`nLastRow` is the value for 100% complete

When the loop is complete, reset it like this:

```
Application.StatusBar = ""
```

Comment: a statusbar is not a progressbar but just equivalent to a percent Label.

Comment: better in what ? i prefer form 100 times better. And secondly, OP clearly has a Userform example (as an image) included in his question.

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind a progressbar is this:

have a userform with a Label (or image or button) with the image of your example photo. Put it in a frame. The width of the frame is initialised to zero and grows as your number grows by either calling a Public Sub inside the userform, of directly `Userform1.Frame1.width=Percent*MaxWidth/100`.
Sometime you would want to add a `doevents`, wich i use only every X cycles (`if clng(percent) mod X = 0 then doevents` , for example).

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: design a progress dialog box. For the following example, it must have the name `frmProgress` and have two text labels `lblMsg1` and `lblMsg2`

Step 2: insert the following code in the dialog's code module:

```
Sub ShowProgressBox()
    Me.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub SetProgressMsg(msg1, msg2)
    If (msg1 <> "") Then Me.lblMsg1 = msg1
    If (msg2 <> "") Then Me.lblMsg2 = msg2
    DoEvents
End Sub

Sub SetProgressTitle(title)
    Me.Caption = title
    DoEvents
End Sub

Sub EndProgressBox()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

You can call these functions from your code to show progress messages.

Step 3: in your code, at the beginning of the lengthy operation, call

```
frmProgress.ShowProgressBox
```

Step 4: during the lengthy operation, regularly call the set function to show the user information, for example in a loop:

```
    frmProgress.SetProgressMsg "Searching in "+ myArray(i), "Working..."
```

Step 5: Once done, close the progress box:

```
    frmProgress.EndProgressBox
```

Comment: A modeless form isn't a dialog (nitpick) - what happens when user dismisses the progress indicator form and the application is still responsive? That's right, user thinks they've cancelled the action, when in reality the code just keeps running and updating the default instance of a form that's no longer displayed. so +1 for not implementing the logic in the form's code-behind, and -1 for using the default instance. Forms are objects, they should be treated as such.

Comment: uh, so what ? you can hide the caption, or the buttons of a Userforms, last time i checked, since i use it all the time...